# Numba Array From Function

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numba

Trying to simply apple numba @njit (No Python mode) for speed in numba but running into errors I do not understand.

Want to declare an array of size n =100, and in the loop want to set each array member with index i in  range (0,100) equal to r**2+5

Why the big stack of errors from numba ?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Spyder Editor

This is a temporary script file.
"""

import numpy as np
from numba import njit


n=100
r=.5
 
Values=np.zeros(n, dtype=np.float64)

@njit
def func(n):
    for i in range(0,n): 
        Values[i]=r**2+5
    return(Values)

print(func(n))
```

Comment: `TypeError: Cannot modify value of type readonly array(float64, 1d, C)` Pass in the array to the function. Always avoid global arrays, especially if you don't know exactly how they are implemented in Numba. `def func(Values,n):` solves the problem.

Comment: Yes this answer the question @max9111 Thanks ! Was wondering if there is a way to bulk assign values to an array without a loop but that include the index in the function. For example x[ArrayIndex i]= 100**(Array Index i)

Comment: @JBerstein Please check the answer I have provided. If it is helpful then please mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with a bit of modification your code as follows:

```
import numpy as np
from numba import njit

@njit
def func(n):
    r = .5
    Values = np.zeros(n, dtype=np.float64)
    for i in range(0, n):
        Values[i] = r ** 2 + 5
    return (Values)
```

---

Or you could do it with much cleaner and pythonic way of list comprehensions. i.e bulk assigning as you called it.

```
@njit
def func1(n):
    vals = np.array([(0.5**2 + 5) for r in range(n)])
    return vals
```